# angular ui.grid [[object HTMLDivElement]] will be displayed instead of data in every cell

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular 1.3 and angular ui bootstrap and ui-grid 3(because of rtl support).

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/btnkvFkn3tMHbIPz0vFz?p=preview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've fixed it using a row template, the only change is adding `{{row.entity[col.field]}}` in the default row template.

Here is the result:

`rowTemplate: "<div><div ng-repeat=\"col in grid.renderedColumns track by $index\" class=\"ui-grid-cell col{{ col.index }}\"><div class=\"ui-grid-vertical-bar\">&nbsp;</div><div class=\"ui-grid-inner-cell-contents\" ui-grid-cell=\"\" col=\"col\" row=\"row\" row-index=\"row.index\" col-index=\"col.colDef.index\">{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div></div>",`